# Ideal CPU core setting for threads ignored, probably since Windows 10 update

Tags: windows, multithreading, scheduler

Since recently (most likely due to a recent Windows 10 update), setting the ideal processor core for a thread using SetThreadIdealProcessor appears to be ignored.

In our software we allow users to specify on which CPU core(s) they want to run specific threads. For our specific application this does work better than just letting Windows decide.

I don't know when it changed exactly, but the setting appears to be completely ignored now; we have received multiple reports about this in the last week. It reproduces on my development system. ProcessExplorer does show that the ideal core is set, but if I look in TaskManager, the CPU core that I've selected isn't doing anything at all. On another (Windows 11) test system it still worked as expected.

I can imagine that there might be something new metric (staying on the same core as much as possible to save power for example) that the scheduler uses that overrides the ideal core setting, but I haven't been able to find any information about that.

Setting a forced affinity mask with the core that we want to run on does still work, but that's not what we want - that makes the behavior less predictable instead of more.